# html is not properly updating using ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, html, ckeditor, tinymce

I updating html using ckeditor and php. but when i update some html is misplaced.

Updating

```html
<nav class="container">
    <span class="cd-marker item-1"></span>
    
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#0"><div class="slide-number">1</div> Money Care<span>Finding your Next Advisor</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#0"><div class="slide-number">2</div> Friendly Assistance<span>Export Financial Advice</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#0"><div class="slide-number">3</div> Our Experience<span>We have 15 Years Experience</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#0"><div class="slide-number">4</div> Client Investment<span>Doing the right thing</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

After update i got output like

```html
<nav class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">
        <div class="slide-number"><a href="#0">1</a></div>
        <a href="#0">Money Care<span>Finding your Next Advisor</span></a></li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide-number"><a href="#0">2</a></div>
        <a href="#0">Friendly Assistance<span>Export Financial Advice</span></a></li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide-number"><a href="#0">3</a></div>
        <a href="#0">Our Experience<span>We have 15 Years Experience</span></a></li>
        <li>
        <div class="slide-number"><a href="#0">4</a></div>
        <a href="#0">Client Investment<span>Doing the right thing</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
```

Please notice that line

```
<div class="slide-number">
```

jumped before tag.

```
 <a>
```

this issue also arise when i use tinymce instead of ckeditor.
I couldn't find any solution anywhere on the net.
Please provide suggestion what could get wrong with editor.

Comment: Technically ckeditor is correct if it's parsing the text as HTML4 or XHTML1 since `<a>` is an inline element it cannot contain the block level `<div>` element; I'm not sure of the exact status of HTML5 support in CKEditor tbh - I think you can roll-your-own DTD if you have to. Seems like it's still an ongoing issue : http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9457

Comment: but WP uses tinymce and don't have any problem with that, why this problem i am facing when using in my own website ?

Comment: I don't really know about TinyMCE - haven't touched it for years; but looking at the old ckeditor forum it seems the only workaround is to hack the DTD; add `CKEDITOR.dtd.a.div = 1;` Alternatively you can replace those `<div>` tags with `<span>` tags (which are inline) and it'll be fine : http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKEditor-wont-allow-inside